# AWS Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow UI Link Redirects to Internal Server Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I keep receiving an "Internal Server Error" redirect when I click the "Open Airflow UI" link in the Amazon MWAA console; it's just a blank white screen with "Internal Server Error" in big black text. I was being successfully redirected to the Airflow UI when I set up the environment, but it appeared to break overnight. It then started working again yesterday, then broke again today overnight.

Please let me know if I can provide further details--thank you!

I have tried and confirmed the following:

- Region is correct with us-west-2
- Logging in and back out as root user with access to everything
- VPC setup and permissions are the same as when the Open Airflow UI was successfully redirecting me
- VPC setup is with the standard AWS Cloudformation template that is provided during MWAA setup
- A token is provided after the `login = true` portion of the URL redirect
- Maintenance window is set as 7 AM UTC, Sunday, so it shouldn't be occurring now

I expect to be redirected to the Airflow UI successfully.

Comment: For some reason, if I try to open the UI link in an incognito window, it works. Maybe it's a local browser cache issue? Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that I expect to be fixed fairly quickly. As a workaround you can delete your browser's cookie whose name corresponds to your Airflow UI link, refresh, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue of MWAA. I am unsure what is the root cause of it, but I've seen this issue for a while. I am using MWAA Airflow 2.4.3. It happened when I tried to access MWAA Airflow UI the day after I deployed it.

You have to delete the cookie. I'll use Chrome to demonstrate it.

Open the `Chrome Developer Tools` and click  `Application` then `Cookie`:
[image]
Click `session` and delete the value.

Now go back to AWS console MWAA environment page and click the `Open Airflow UI` button again, you should be able to access Airflow UI.

Hope this helps.